# How to read .tagger file that comes with stanford pos tagger

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger, maxent, treetagger

I cant read the .tagger file which comes with the stanford maxent tagger for my language with a text editor. How could I view the contents of the .tagger file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .tagger file is a serialized version of a POS tagging model, so it is not human readable.